# Modify Invoice in Odoo

Tags: reporting, odoo, odoo-8

I'm modifying report_invoice.xml which is located in account/views/report_invoice.xml in order to change some text and some format of the invoice but when i override the file in the server, the invoice is still showing the original information.

Does anyone know how to reflect the changes?

Comment: Did you added your inherited file into __openerp__.py file ? and also required to update module, when you made any changes into the xml it's required to update module.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologies i did not add any file, i just modify the original one (keeping one safe copy in case i did something wrong). I have my ODOO instance in MyERPEngine, do you know how can i update the module (i think is account module)? It's from ODOO itself or do i have to do something else?

Comment: To update account module you need to go to settings -> Installed modules -> search account module and upgrade it, generally it's not advisable to change the main content, if you want to extend the functionality you need to inherit that view or model according to your need. By this way use can make extensible functionality. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

if you have printed the invoice the original information stays until you delete the INV*.pdf(s) from the attachments.

just noticed after fighting for two days.. XD